# Get index of each overlapping occurrence in string without for or while loops

Tags: javascript

I'd like to get the index of each **overlapping** occurrence in a given string.

For example:

```
var source = 'NNNHRMSLGGGGEAZZ'
var toFind = ['HRMSL', 'NN', 'ZZ', 'GGG']
find(source, toFind) // should print line by line:  'NN' found at index 0
                                                    'NN' found at index 1
                                                    'HRMSL' found at index 2
                                                    'GGG' found at index 8
                                                    'GGG' found at index 9
                                                    'ZZ' found at index 13
```

How can I achieve this without using `for` or `while` loops (`forEach` is fine)?

I tried doing it multiple ways but all of them don't take into account overlapping items, which is quite tricky to do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please show what you tried & what the problem was with it.

Comment: Why no `for` or `while` loops? They *would* be the best technique to deal with this sort of thing. They aren't necessary, but they'd make the code look nicer

Comment: Can you explain the intent behind your latest edit to your question? It doesn't add anything and makes your question ambiguous and unclear. Is this a new question or the same one as before?

Comment: I've rolled back to the original question to make it more clear to future readers. If you have a new question please post it as a new question. If you want to edit your old question, add onto the current one rather than deleting your entire original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `reduce` to create an object, with key as arr element and value as array of indexes, then iterate over the object keys and check if it's array length is greater than 1. If yes, it is an duplicate element.

```js
const arr = ["a","v","a"];

const groupByDuplicateElements = arr.reduce((a, e, i) => {
    if(!a[e]) {
        a[e] = [];
    }
    a[e].push(i);
    return a;
}, {});

Object.keys(groupByDuplicateElements).forEach(key => {
    if(groupByDuplicateElements[key].length > 1) {
        console.log(`${groupByDuplicateElements[key].join(',')}("${key}")`);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive call to `indexOf()` to find overlapping items by providing a starting index for a given item based on the previously found index. Then, for each item in your array, you can `.flatMap()` each item-index pair to its own array. You can then sort this array and then iterate over it using forEach:

```js
const source = 'NNNHRMSLGGGGEAZZ';
const toFind = ['HRMSL', 'NN', 'ZZ', 'GGG'];

const index = (str, item, i = 0) => {
  const idx = str.indexOf(item, i);
  return idx >= 0 ? [[item, idx], ...index(str, item, idx+1)] : []
}
const getIndexPairs = (source, toFind) =>
  toFind.flatMap(item => index(source, item)).sort(([,a], [,b])=>a-b);
  
getIndexPairs(source, toFind).forEach(([item, index]) => {
  console.log(item +" found at index: " +index);
});
```

Comment: @libgo this is a completely new question. You're better off posting it as a new one. You can roll back the current one to the old question and then post a new question.

Comment: @libgo please read this: [Can I change a question to another question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291949/can-i-change-a-question-to-another-question) and this: [Should I edit my question, or create a new one?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266140/should-i-edit-my-question-or-create-a-new-one)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to deal with overlapping items would be to iterate over each `toFind` separately, and when on the `source` string, iterate character-by-character, checking to see if the haystack, sliced at that point, `startsWith` the needle:

```js
const find = (source, toFind) => {
  const logs = [];
  toFind.forEach((find) => {
    [...source].forEach((_, index) => {
      if (source.slice(index).startsWith(find)) {
        logs.push(({ index, find }));
      }
    });
  });
  logs.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index);
  logs.forEach(({ find, index}) => {
    console.log(`${find} found at index ${index}`);
  });
};

var source = 'NNNHRMSLGGGGEAZZ'
var toFind = ['HRMSL', 'AA', 'ZZ', 'GGG']
find(source, toFind)
```